# CP entry instructions on multiple lines

Tags: control-panel

I would like to make instruction field info on multiple lines in CP to improve legibility.
You can make a line return when you input the field instructions but it does not work.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I got it. Just after posting this I had a last intuition of trying markdown stuff and it works! Cf Stackexchange line return...
*Asking the question gives you the answer!*

**So just add 2 spaces at end of line!**
[image]